# trying to set a variable from a string with localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying out a test with local storage that I thought would be rather simple. I am trying to grab content created with a CMS, in this case, wordpress, and store it to use throughout the site as a sidebar widget.

Long story short, there is some crazy plugin that creates some content on the homepage that I want, but doesn't allow me to use it as a widget throughout the site. Before anyone asks, no I can't modify the plugin.

I start off with a simple example:

`var helloTest = "Hello World!";
    localStorage.setItem("test", helloTest); //It's saved!
    var test = localStorage.getItem("test"); //Let's grab it and save it to a variable
    console.warn(test); //Logs "Hello World!"`

Then I try to modify it a bit by getting some html content via jQuery:

`var helloTest = jQuery('#desiredDiv').html();
    localStorage.setItem("test", helloTest); 
    var test = localStorage.getItem("test"); 
    console.warn(test);`

On the homepage, the variable is returned in the console as desired. But all that is returned on any interior pages is "undefined".

All of the examples that I'm finding for local storage seem way more complex than what I'm trying to do. Am I missing something??

Comment: Maybe I'm approaching this thing completely incorrectly.

Comment: it's jQuery not jquery

Comment: sorry that's a typo. I'm using jQuery in my code. I'll make the edit.

Comment: why do you want to do it?

Comment: I think what you need to do is if the page has an element with id `desiredDiv` then set its content to the storage... if there is no element then read the content from the storage...

Comment: The problem could be that only the home page has the element with id `desiredDiv`

Comment: something like `var $el = jQuery('#desiredDiv'),
    test;
if ($el.length) {
    test = $el.html();
    localStorage.setItem("test", test);
} else {
    test = localStorage.getItem("test");
}
console.warn(test);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have a plugin that allows the user to create content with and display it as an element on the homepage. But I also want that same exact content used throughout the site as a widget. But there is no way to get this data from the plugin to a widget. I tried.

Answer (score 0):

The element with the id `desiredDiv` must be present in all pages, if you are setting on page load basis.

Comment: So maybe I'm completely misunderstanding the concept of local storage. I can't set a variable on one page, in this case a string of html content from "#desiredDiv" and then use it as a variable to append to an element on another page?

Comment: @JeremyMiller, the element has to be present in the page otherwise jquery will return undefined which is saved.

Comment: So all I would need to do is return an empty element? Wouldn't it set a new variable each time to an empty string if the element is empty?

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and it did what I expected. It returned a blank string.